# Will loan enforcement notice (namsfogden) affect my visa renewal?

Tags: working-visas, norway, credit-history, loan

I have been served a notice for not paying the loan by the enforcement department in Norway which comes under Police since 2007. I have a visa renewal appointment in 4 days. Will it affect my renewal?

Note: Its called Namsfogden in Norwegian.